# Bulk uninstall applications

Tags: uninstallation, applications

I like to try out lots of apps. Often a site like Lifehacker or Droidlife will feature several that are similar in functionality and I will install them all in order to compare features.

That leaves me with lots and lots of applications that I end up not wanting to keep. Unfortunately, I can only uninstall one at a time.

Is there an app or method that would allow me to uninstall a bunch at a time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are tons of apps that do batch uninstalling but here's a simple free one that I know works: [Uninstaller Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.adao.android.aun)

A lot of the more full featured app managers also have a batch uninstall option.  I like to consolidate functions into as few apps as I can.  Now I use [SmartBar](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.aps.smartbar) which has a good app manager with batch uninstall.

Comment: I tried both smart bar and uninstaller pro, and get prompted to confirm for each app and after the uninstall, so to uninstall 50 apps I have to tap on 100 OK buttons. Is this SN android security feature / limitation?

Answer (score 2):

**Scripted via adb & pm (package manager)**:

If the SDK is installed and you like to use the commandline, that's about the quickest way I know of:

Downside: you only get to see the package names, not the friendly application names (There's seemingly no easy cli way. For programmers: [get application name from package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name))
Downside 2: Be sure what you do, you might uninstall every app on your phone if you don't edit the list.

```
 # Use android's package manager 'pm'  
 # list all 3rd party pkgs (using the '-3' parameter)  
me@local:~$ adb shell pm list packages -3 > /tmp/pkg.list  
 # Use whatever editor you like (grep, vi, GUI) to edit the list  
me@local:~$ vi /tmp/pkg.list  
me@local:~$ cat /tmp/pkg.list | sed 's,.*:,,' | while read a; do adb uninstall $a;done
```

**Maybe also an improvement for a limited number of apps:**

Google's Play Store now offers improved per device management (since around Google I|O 2012):

Go to [My Android Apps](https://play.google.com/apps) (login required) and you see "Apps installed on [Device Model]". Per app you have an:

- Update button (if there's an update)
- Uninstall button (except for system apps)

Using this you can easily uninstall apps on specific phones or tablets using your internet browser.

See also this accepted answer: [Remotely uninstall apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24847/remotely-uninstall-apps)

Comment: While updating and uninstalling from the web Store makes things much easier (I really like it) you still need to do each app one at a time.

Comment: @Al Everett: Added scripted solution also. Better? :-)

Comment: It's an option. Not one that will work for me, but someone else can probably benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I used it, but [AppBrain's app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps) will let you sync to your AppBrain account...  so it should uninstall apps you remove from your AppBrain account, but I can't verify that since I don't use it anymore.

Not a batch uninstall, but in LauncherPro you can drag and drop apps to the trash can, hover for a few seconds, and then drop to uninstall it (instead of removing it from the homescreen).  Works from the app drawer too.  This is the method I usually use.

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton, aren't there?

One I'm looking at is [Apps Uninstall](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tw.nicky.AppsUninstall).

A nice feature it has is the ability to mark apps to protect them from accidentally bulk uninstalling.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem with his method and most other methods I have seen (at least on my [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6 and [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) 10 machines) is that CRLFs were at the end of each line of the `/tmp/pkg.list` file, so the uninstaller instead of uninstalling `com.google.chrome`, was actually attempting to uninstall 'com.google.chrome^M'  ... notice the CR return character. By doing dos2unix, there is 'Success', not 'Failure'. His [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) script may have originally been a substitute for dos2unix, but was mangled when posted.

```
[CentOS6]# adb shell pm list packages > /tmp/pkg.list.txt
[CentOS6]# adb push /tmp/pkg.list.txt /tmp/
[CentOS6]# adb shell
android:/root # dos2unix /tmp/pkg.list.txt
android:/root # for f in \`cat /tmp/pkg.list.txt\`; do echo $f; pm uninstall $f; done;
```

The 'Failure' problem has more to do with the [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) shell appending a DOS line ending ^M (on CentOS Linux anyway).

Since I did everything from CentOS 6, I was surprised to be bitten yet again by 1980s technology that was never as good as the technology from 1969. I guess Google wanted to make things easier for Windows users of the ADB shell.

(I had edited (appended) to ce4's answer, but apparently that did not take.)

Comment: Also, *for windows users of the adb shell* hmmm... you did not happen to be using notepad or similar? They do not handle Un*x format files - [Notepad2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad2/) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) would have been a better choice in which it can handle that :)

Comment: i bulk uninstalled a bunch of applications to copy to /system/app/ because my phone is stuck in safe-mode.  The phone is still booting.  i believe i should be able to provide proof that adb itself even when run on Linux is appending DOS newline characters.   No windows was involved, i mainly use CentOS, Ubuntu 10, and other flavors of *nix.  i only use windows to administer ADS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7854/discussion-between-rjt-and-t0mm13b)

Comment: How does this even answer the question?

Comment: Al, the question was how to bulk uninstall applications, the script i posted above does exactly that.  Notice the 'pm uninstall' part.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users, after generating the list packages like this

```
adb shell pm list packages -3 > pkg_third.txt
```

Open and edit this file, leave only packages that will be REMOVED.

In **PowerShell**, execute this script

```
Get-Content '.\pkg_third.txt' | ForEach-Object {

    $packageNameCleaned = $_ -replace '.*:', ''
    Write-Host "Removing $packageNameCleaned" 
    & adb uninstall $packageNameCleaned
}
```