# Remotely uninstall apps?

Tags: applications, uninstallation

I have tried through the Google Play store and it does not seem possible from there, but does anyone know if it is possible to remove an application remotely?

In other words, *if I do not have direct access to my phone*, can I make use of some website, app or service to uninstall an app without being able to interact with the phone directly.

Comment: It seems now it's possible trough Google Play, have you checked it today?

Comment: I had not, but it is! Obviously it was my concern that spurned this addition by Google ;)  See the accepted answer for more details!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Google Play **website**, as accessed through a web browser, the answer to this question depends on *when* you are asking:

- In 2012 (when this question was asked): in the "My Apps" or "My Android Apps" list, use the little trashcan to uninstall.
- In October 2014, [when asked again](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85846/remotely-uninstall-an-app-via-play-store) it was not possible using the web interface, instead the Google Play Store App is required.

Answer (score 7):

If your phone is on the same local Wi-Fi network as your computer then you could use [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en) for this. If it's not, then [Remote Desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rm&hl=en) offers a terminal emulator, so you could use that to uninstall the app from the command line:

```
pm uninstall app.package.name
```

Alternatively, you could set up an SSH server and then use the above `pm` command. [Is there some SSH server for android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9905/is-there-some-ssh-server-for-android) is a good place to start if you need SSH server software. Also note that using `pm uninstall` from outside `adb shell` - such as in a terminal emulator - will require root. I am unsure if Airdroid requires root for its uninstall feature.

Comment: _love_ Remote Desktop! However, does not completely solve the issue if a Remote Desktop server is not running when access to the phone is lost. Unless you can also remotely begin a session?

Comment: @jlehenbauer: I think in that situation SSH would be your best bet. Otherwise you'd have to leave Remote Desktop (or some similar app) running all the time, AFAIK. I don't think that will allow you to remotely start a session, and I'm not familiar with any apps that support that feature.

Comment: Note that these solutions require a rooted device.  Without that, only adb and other system components can accomplish silent uninstalls; anything else can only use an intent to begin a user-confirmed uninstall.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: `pm  uninstall` does not require root (neither does `adb uninstall`, for that matter). I have no idea if Airdroid does, I have not tested that one myself.

Comment: Without root, pm uninstall does require the privileges of the shell user which adb runs as when it is not root.  An application cannot run things as the shell user, unless you've left something started via adb running for it to use.  So for example, if you run an ssh server from adb, you can do this; but if you run it from an app, you cannot.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Ah, sorry, I see what you meant now (and you're right).

Answer (score 7):

> Though it went unmentioned during today's Google I/O keynote, the Google Play website now offers the option of updating and/or uninstalling apps from Android hardware directly in the browser. By heading to the "My Android Apps" tab of the Play portal, you'll see a list of all applications that reside on your smartphone or tablet; users with multiple devices can view a breakdown of what apps are installed where. Though sorting is alphabetical, apps with pending available updates will be listed first. Clicking a gray update button will immediately start the download on the target Android product, though sadly there's no "update all" option just yet. Uninstalls are equally as simple: selecting the trash can icon underneath each app first brings up a warning dialog that acts as a nice safeguard against unintentional deletions. Clicking through this leads to the immediate removal of the app in question from your device.

Source: http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/27/3121959/google-play-website-update-uninstall-android-apps

Comment: It's possible that I'm just blind, but it looks to me like a redesign sometime in the past two years has removed this feature from the Play Store website.

Answer (score 4):

[Appbrain](http://www.appbrain.com) provides this feature. But you have to get an account and install the Appbrain App.