# Remotely uninstall an app via Play Store

Tags: applications, google-play-store, uninstallation

Is it still possible to remotely uninstall an android application from a web browser via the Google Play Store?

According to the question that this is a supposed duplicate of, this was possible in 2012, but it seems to no longer be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparantly not. The Google Play Help [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2521768) states that you have to uninstall the apps from your device. Either via the Play Store app, or via settings.