# Removing multiple entries easily from the Google Play Store's "My apps & games" library

Tags: google-play-store

I have so many apps in my Google Play Store's library, and I want to delete all of them. However, individually deleting each one would be tedious.

Are there any easier/more convenient ways to remove multiple apps from there?

Answer (score 1):

Google Store doesn't offer a public API like most Google products/services, thus writing an app or service with this capability would be a tedious work, and would require probably some low-level hacking and analyzing the protocols of the Google. On my best knowledge, no one did it until now.

According [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/96929/50837), until around 2012, we could uninstall our apps from the web, which could have been a quicker option. Since then, even that was not possible any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Tasker" or any other type of automation apps to automate the process of removing each item (app) from the library. Then, program the tasker to repeat that process. I generally do this for repeated actions.

Comment: This seems like a lazy answer or a throwaway answer. Your intention might be right to answer this, but the result is not up to the mark. Consider editing this answer to add the necessary detail, which involves the steps needed to use Tasker to achieve the objective.