# Mass uninstall apps

Tags: applications, uninstallation

My phone is massively cluttered - I've got something on the order of 50 (!) apps I am not using at all. I could manually uninstall them, but the wait for the uninstallation to finish between selecting the next one would drive me crazy.

Is there a way to, at least, create a list of apps to be uninstalled all together? I'm not afraid of using ADB, but don't want to root the phone. I'd also prefer not to use 3rd party apps.

My phone is Xiaomi Mi A3 (Android One), with Android 9.

Order of preference for methods:

1. Google Play on PC (website)
2. Phone settings or similar (no 3rd party app)
3. ADB or other debug interface, without rooting
4. 3rd party app

Comment: ADB (no root needed) should be possible as per [Bulk uninstall applications](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1525/44325). The "Google Play on PC" method seems to disappear around/before 2014 though.

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks, that should work. I'd say this is a duplicate, but the linked question is 10 years old.

Comment: This app works well. Though 3rd party apps aren't preferred by you https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splendapps.shark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this from a different direction, to backup the data from the phone you want to keep, then do a [factory reset](https://support.google.com/android/answer/6088915?hl=en) which will effectively remove all the apps and allow you to reinstall what you now require.
It will also remove any orphaned data and folders that uninstalling the apps could leave behind.

Comment: that's how i would do it too

Comment: Accepting, since this is what happened in the end - I bought a new phone and only moved a few apps over.

Answer (score 2):

Using the python tool [AMDH](https://github.com/SecTheTech/AMDH), that use ADB, with the option '-l' (list applications) with the argument '-t e' (list all enabled applications, including system apps) will list numbered installed applications by package name. You can select applications numbers separated by comma and choose the action uninstall ('u'). **Uninstalling some system apps can break your system**, you can use disable action instead of uninstall if you are not sure that the application is mandatory for the system.